# how can I play a sound clip on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

how can I play a sound clip on page load?Is there any javascript or jquery to do that?I am creating my page in php.

Comment: Don't. Really really don't. There is little on the web that is more annoying than unrequested noise coming out of speakers.

Comment: You know what else you should consider?  A Flash Intro.  That you can't skip.

Answer (score 3):

Through simple HTML.

```
<object>
<param name="autostart" value="true">
<param name="src" value="sound.mp3">
<param name="autoplay" value="true"> 
<param name="controller" value="true">
<embed src="sound.mp3" controller="true" autoplay="true" autostart="True" type="audio/mp3" />
</object>
```

Comment: I applied this code into my page, but have no sound play .. :(

Answer (score 1):

you can pull this off with straight html

http://www.webreference.com/js/column20/bgsound.html

or

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/sounds/_BGSOUND.html

I think wav, mid, and mp3 are supported

Answer (score 1):

You can also combine the answers from premiso and CheeseConQueso with HTML5 audio tag:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_audio_and_video_in_firefox

Answer (score 0):

The question was actually about how to do it in javascript.

```
var aClip = new Audio (path_to_file or URL);
aClip.play();
```