# audio file does not autoplay within template

Tags: audio, meteor, autoplay

Issues when using Meteor with default Handlebars template.
When I move the tag below into the html body, it autoplays just fine. But in the context of a handlebars template, I see the controls but it does not autoplay. Any way to overcome this??

```
<template name="showMedia">
  <div class="background_audio">
    <audio controls autoplay> 
         <source src="assets/screenDisplayAlert.wav">
    </audio>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Template.showMedia.rendered` to execute some code after Meteor has rendered the template. For instance, you could call audio.play() or re-apply any missing autoplay attributes.

The reason this isn't working may have something to do with when the browser hooks up autoplay. Being re-rendered by Meteor may not invoke those same hooks. Personally, I feel like that should "just work". If you can't get it fixed, you might consider [filing a bug on Github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues) to see if the devs can reproduce or figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding some javascript inside a `Meteor.startup()` block on the client.  For reference see [Starting and Stopping Audio in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927838/starting-and-stopping-audio-in-javascript) and [how can I play a sound clip on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362426/how-can-i-play-a-sound-clip-on-page-load).

I don't know why it works outside a template and not inside, but I'm pretty sure the JS will work, and discretion is the better part of valor :)

Comment: The problem is that the audio files are being served from a reactive source, so the file changes. I suppose I could 'bind' through JQuery and play explicitly through javascript, but it seems excessive.